# Access violation error at 0x1C

Tags: assembly, arm, keil

I have the following ARM code:

```
            AREA prog, code, READONLY
            ENTRY

            MOV r1, #0      ;division count
            MOV r2, #41     ;Fahrenheit

            SUB r2, r2, #32             ;r2=r2-32
            ADD r3, r2, r2, LSL #2      ;r3=r2*5

LOOP
            ADD r1, r1, #1
            SUBS r3, r3, #9
            BLT LOOP

            END
```

And I am getting the following error:

```
*** error 65: access violation at 0x0000001C : no 'execute/read' permission
```

As soon as the debugger hits the `BLT LOOP` line, the Program Counter (PC) value jumps from 0x18 to 0x1C.

I am new to ARM coding, and I am using Keil to execute this code.

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: Shouldn't you have some sort of system call to exit back to the debugger? See http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/armasm/armasm_dom1359731144051.htm

Comment: if 0x18 is the BLT, then 0x1C is the first instruction after it. you didn't write any code for that address, so when you leave the loop, random code is executed. Add an instruction to halt there, or an endless loop